# How to restore the mysql default permissions that allow creating/using test_* databases for all users

Tags: permissions

Somehow one of my MySQL servers is configured in a way that users can't create Databases named 'test_foo' anymore. I would like to restore the default rules that come with fresh MySQL installations because I need test_ databases for a test suite my application wants to run.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it: Running/usr/bin/mysql_install_db fixed the default permissions. However, it also seems to have destroyed some other privileges - I had to grant them again, so use this with caution (and good backups)

Comment: This is a workaround, but not a good enough solution. I have many permissions already set, and I don't want to lose all of them.